# How can I do real-time mesh deformation?

Tags: c++, mesh, soft-body-dynamics

I have a very simple problem: I have a icosphere mesh rendered with OpenGL and I want to deform/stretch it. But it has to be a real-time process because the deformation is generated when user drag'n drop a part of the mesh. The idea is to let the user models the shape like a ball of play dough.

I already tried the biharmonic deformation functionality of [libigl](https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/#biharmonic-deformation). The results are good but the performances are terrible, far from real-time.
I also look into Bullet Physics and its soft bodies but it seems they are just elastic and return to their initial shape when you release them. I need to keep the deformed shape.

How do I  achieve this result? (I just thought of replacing my mesh with a group of rigid spheres stick together and spawning new spheres when user drag'n drop the 'volume' to extend it)

Thank for your help

Comment: There was a cute "manipulator" technique explained in [Bleeding-Edge Effects on Mobile](https://gdcvault.com/play/1026744/Bleeding-Edge-Effects-on) (about halfway in). You could support n simultaneous touches and drags in your shader, then on release, update your mesh CPU-side to bake-in the resulting vertex coordinates to that you can support another n simultaneous drags in a second step, without having to keep track of n+n+n+n... manipulators worth of history all at once. After each drag operation, the output gets baked down as the new input for the next operation.

Comment: I think I've seen an implementation based on this: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/meshpapers/SCOLARS.pdf